# Is it possible to find the limit without l'Hopital's Rule or series

Tags: calculus, limits

Is it possible to find $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(1-\cos(x))}{x^2e^x}$$
without using L'Hopital's Rule or Series or anything complex but just basic knowledge (definition of a limit, limit laws, and algebraic expansion / cancelling?)

Answer (score 4):

Multiply and divide the numerator and denominator by $1-\cos(x)$.

Then just basic trigonometric limits to evaluate the answer.

Comment: Can you cancel the 1-cos(x) when sin of it is being taken? I wouldn't think it would cancel without dividing by sin(1-cos(x))

Comment: @user: No, you can't. You're correct to doubt it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  To specify it isn't sinx(1-cos(x)) although that is what I thought when I first looked at it as well, it's sin(1-cos(x)).

Comment: "Multiply and divide"? That would bring each of them back to their original form wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(1 - \cos x)}{\mathrm{e}^x \cdot x^2}
  &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(1 - \cos x)}{1 - \cos x} 
            \cdot \frac{1 - \cos x}{x^2} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{- x} \\
  &= \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\sin u}{u}
            \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos x}{x^2}
           \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \mathrm{e}^{- x} \\
  &= 1\cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2 \sin^2 \frac{x}{2}}{x^2} \cdot 1 \\
  &= \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{2 \sin^2 u}{4 u^2}
\end{align}

Comment: There's still a limit as x goes to 0 of something over x^2 which makes it not work..

Comment: @user155301: I dont get what issue you face with $x^{2}$

Comment: @user155301 even if your proof can't use series, look at the series for $\cos x$...

Comment: we have $(1 - \cos x)/x^{2} = 2\sin^{2}(x/2)/x^{2} = 2\sin^{2}(x/2)/(x/2)^{2}\cdot(x/2)^{2}/x^{2} \to 2/4 = 1/2$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh not in my version of trigonometry... :-)

Comment: @vonbrand: i don't see any issue with $1 - \cos x = 2\sin^{2}(x/2)$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh seems I saw your comment halfway through writing it. Sorry.

Comment: This looks a lot like applying l'Hôpital and then the chain rule, but without saying so, doing everything by hand instead.

Comment: It's just applying the answer by user3628041

Answer (score 3):

We can proceed as follows: $$\begin{aligned}L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(1 - \cos x)}{x^{2}e^{x}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(1 - \cos x)}{1 - \cos x}\cdot\frac{1 - \cos x}{x^{2}e^{x}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(1 - \cos x)}{1 - \cos x}\cdot\frac{1 - \cos x}{x^{2}}\cdot \frac{1}{e^{x}}\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos x}{x^{2}}\cdot \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{e^{x}}\text{ by putting }t = 1 - \cos x \to 0 \text{ as } x \to 0\\
&= 1\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos x}{x^{2}}\cdot 1\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2\sin^{2}(x/2)}{(x/2)^{2}}\cdot\frac{(x/2)^{2}}{x^{2}}\\
&= 2\cdot 1\cdot\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{2}\end{aligned}$$

Comment: I delete my answer to avoid irregular downvotes but how did you explain the other answers on [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/815951/123277)? It seems they all (except yours) used the same method like I used. I really appreciate if you want to discuss this issue to me.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey: All the other answers (except mine) in that linked post work on this theorem: if $f(x) \to A$ and $g(x) \to B$ and $A > 0$ then $\{f(x)\}^{g(x)} \to A^{B}$.

Comment: OK, I can accept your argument. Thanks.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey: by the way thanks for the discussion. You may visit my blog post http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/11/teach-yourself-limits-in-8-hours-part-2.html for more details (especially the section on "Misuse of Rules of Limits"

Comment: OK, +1 for your answer.